# System.Web.Providers -> Microsoft.AspNet.Providers?

Tags: asp.net, nuget

[Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers 1.1](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers) were released yesterday together with [System.Web.Providers 1.2](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers/1.2). On latter nuget page states: `Legacy package, System.Web.Providers is now included in the 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers' package.`

Is this only name change or something more interesting/important? Should I remove `System.Web.Providers` 1.2 package reference if I have `Microsoft.AspNet.Providers` 1.1 and `Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core` 1.0 referenced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You nailed it when you quoted, "Legacy package, System.Web.Providers is now included in the 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers' package."  You can remove System.Web.Providers and just use the other two packages.

I read the original [post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) and compared it to the description for the "new" Microsoft.AspNet.Providers 1.1.  They both say that this package of providers is the same except it supports SQL Azure and SQL Compact edition.